# Can't use ES modules in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a very basic Google Cloud serverless application using Node.js, but it keeps showing the following error on Google Cloud Console:

```
Provided module can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /workspace/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /workspace/index.js from /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /workspace/package.json.
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:13)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
 at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
 at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
 at Object.getUserFunction (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js:29:32)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/index.js:77:32)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
Could not load the function, shutting down.
```

Here's my *index.js* file:

```js
export function foobar(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send("Hello World!");
}
```

Here's my *package.json* file:

```json
{
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  ...
}
```

I'm running it using

```
gcloud functions deploy foobar --region europe-west1 --runtime nodejs14 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

I've already tried the following:

1. renaming *index.js* to *index.mjs* and change `"main": "index.js"` to `"main": "index.mjs"` in *package.json* (the error persists)
2. solution 1 plus removing `"type": "module"` from *package.json* (the error persists)
3. removing `"type": "module"` from *package.json* (raises a SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export')
4. renaming *index.js* to *index.cjs* and change `"main": "index.js"` to `"main": "index.cjs"` in *package.json* (raises a SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export')
5. solution 4 plus removing `"type": "module"` from *package.json* (raises a SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export')
6. adding the `--experimental-modules` flag in `gcloud functions deploy` (shows unrecognized arguments: --experimental-modules)
7. solution 6 but replacing `gcloud functions deploy` with `gcloud beta functions deploy` (shows unrecognized arguments: --experimental-modules)
8. uninstalling Google Cloud SDK completely and trying all above solutions again

The only solution that worked was solution 3 plus using

```js
exports.foobar = (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello World!");
}
```

However, I want to use it for a Telegram bot with the [`node-telegram-bot-api` module](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api), but because I removed `"type": "module"` from *package.json*, it raises "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when I import the Telegram API.

The project structure was created using `npm init`, as shown below.

```
.
├── index.js
└── package.json
```

Any thoughts? My Node.js version is v14.17.0 and my Google Cloud SDK version is v342.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Functions (and therefore Firebase Functions) does not support ESM modules yet:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/233
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2994

Now I think you are conflating using and packaging ES modules. You don't have to package your functions code as an ES module in order to use `node-telegram-bot-api` module. Just import it using `require` syntax instead of using the `import` syntax.

Comment: Google Cloud Functions just announced support for ES modules! https://medium.com/google-cloud/es-modules-in-cloud-functions-f5be1676c8b5

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
   
exports.foobar= functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Hello World!");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did `npm install firebase-functions`. When I ran it locally, it showed the warning "FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail". When I ran it using `gcloud`, [the Log Console displayed](http://i.imgur.com/7O38zSy.png) "Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin". Since I'm using only Google Cloud Functions, will I have to set up Firebase in order to make it work?

Comment: I suggest you to follow the documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Answer (score 0):

Execute this code inside a Google Cloud Functions to know which version of Node.js is running.

```
console.log(`Hello Node.js v${process.versions.node}!`);
```

I think Google Cloud required: node: '12' (Same that Firebase)

With the release of Node version 15.3.0, ES modules can be used without an experimental flag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It showed "Hello Node.js v14.17.0!" [in the Log Console](http://i.imgur.com/tnRsGPA.png). Should I downgrade or upgrade it?

Comment: The minimum Node version to use ES modules can be used without an experimental flag is 15.3.0.

If Google Cloud allows you to upgrade the Node.js version upgrade it, if not try if you can use  an experimental flag or do not use ES modules

Answer (score 0):

If someone is struggling to run typescript with ts-node, try this configuration

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --loader ts-node/esm node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/main.js --target=default"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.1.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1"
  }
}
```

index.ts

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express'

export default async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // your code
}
```